# Eigenvalues of an infinite block upper triangular matrix

Tags: compact-operators, infinite-matrices

Suppose that I have a compact operator on a separable complex Hilbert space $T:H \to H$.

Furthermore suppose that with respect to a suitable orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$, the matrix of $T$ takes the form of a bi-infinite block-upper-triangular matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
\cdots & B_{-1} & \ast & \ast & \ast & \cdots\\
\cdots & 0  & B_0 & \ast & \ast & \cdots\\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & B_1 & \ast & \cdots\\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & B_2 & \cdots \\
 \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the $B_k$ $(k \in \mathbb Z)$ are some square matrices, the 0's correspond to rectangular 0 matrices and $\ast$ can be anything at all.

**Question.** Is it true that the eigenvalues of $T$ correspond to the eigenvalues of the $B_k$, as in the finite dimensional case?